# Adding Auto-Generated SQLSERVER Scrips within if statements (Begin, End)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to create a large script of database changes that I made for each release in SQLServer-2008. All of the scripts for each release are wrapped in the BEGIN and END tags of an if statement for that release.

Most of the scripts that I manually create are fine, but if I do something like add a new field in the middle of a table rather then at the end the SQLSERVER auto-generated script is fairly large, creates a `trigger`, `temp table`, etc.

I noticed that I had to remove all of the GO Statements in all of my scripts. After removing all of them **I still get the following error:**

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10641
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.*

I then attempted to wrap all of the triggers in `EXEC('')` statements and I still get an error:

> *Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Procedure T_I_ProformaWhatIf, Line 5
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') 
>   FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 
>   WHERE spid = @@spid*

Below is an example of one of the scripts that I can't put within IF, BEGIN, END:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table1
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Column1 int NOT NULL,
    Column2 int NOT NULL,
    Column3 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    NewColumn nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Column4 float(53) NULL,
    Column5 float(53) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table1 ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Table1 (Id, Column1, Column2, Column3, NewColumn, Column4, Column5)
        SELECT Id, Column1, Column2, Column3, NewColumn, Column4, Column5 FROM dbo.Table1 WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table1 OFF
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Table1', N'Table1', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Column1,
    Column3,
    Column3
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
create TRIGGER [dbo].[T_I_Table1] ON dbo.Table1 
    FOR INSERT 
    AS 
DECLARE @UserName varchar(50) 
SELECT @UserName = REPLACE(CAST(context_info AS VARCHAR(50)), CHAR(0), '') 
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 
WHERE spid = @@spid 

IF (ASCII(@UserName) <> 0)  
begin   
    Update Table1 
    SET InsertUserId = @UserName, 
    InsertDate = GetDate(), 
    UpdateUserId = @UserName, 
    UpdateDate = GetDate() 
    FROM inserted 
    WHERE Table1.Id = inserted.Id 
END
else
BEGIN
    Update Table1 
    SET InsertDate = GetDate(), 
    UpdateDate = GetDate() 
    FROM inserted 
    WHERE Table1.Id = inserted.Id 
END
GO
create TRIGGER [dbo].[T_U_Table1] ON dbo.Table1 
    FOR UPDATE 
    AS 
DECLARE @UserName varchar(50) 
SELECT @UserName = REPLACE(CAST(context_info AS VARCHAR(50)), CHAR(0), '') 
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 
WHERE spid = @@spid 

IF (ASCII(@UserName) <> 0)  
    begin   
    UPDATE Table1 
    SET UpdateUserId = @UserName, 
    UpdateDate = GetDate() 
    FROM inserted 
    WHERE Table1.Id = inserted.Id 
END
else
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1 
    SET  UpdateDate = GetDate() 
    FROM inserted 
    WHERE Table1.Id = inserted.Id 
END
GO
COMMIT
select Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table1', 'Object', 'ALTER') as ALT_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table1', 'Object', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as View_def_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table1', 'Object', 'CONTROL') as Contr_Per
```

Any suggestions or advice on a better way to do this whole thing would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After going through it again wrapping the TRIGGERS in EXEC('') ended up working.

**The 2 tricks here are the following:**

1. Remove all GO Statements
2. Wrap create TRIGGER statements in EXEC('') such as

   EXEC('create TRIGGER [dbo].[T_U_Table1] ON dbo.Table1').....